# How to logout from facebook in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, logout, laravel-socialite

I am using laravel framework and sociallite pacakage of laravel. I have done everything expect one thing logout from facebook. I have successfully logged in with facebook but I want when user logout from our laravel site it should automatic logout from facebook also. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: by logout from facebook you mean logout from your app when logged by facebook, or you want to logout user on facebook.com site?

Comment: yes suppose my site in exmaple.com if i logged inf from example.com  using facebook and after i logged out from example.com and it should also logout from facebook.com

Comment: Just delete the access token

Comment: This is only possible, if the user logged into Facebook to log into your app. If they were logged into Facebook before already, then they will get logged out of your app at most.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal logout functionality included in laravel user scaffolding 
It removes the users session

I think you are confused because when you login with facebook for the second time you are not asked for the confirmation. What you are doing is creating a new session while you click the facebook authentication button.